# Evaluate $\int_{s}^{} \int_{}^{} \; (x^2+y^2) \; dS$ where $S: z=xy$, $ \; \;x^2+y^2 \leq 4$ $\; \; x \geq 0 \; \; y\geq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\int_{s}^{} \int_{}^{} \; (x^2+y^2) \; dS$ where $S: z=xy$, $ \; \;x^2+y^2 \leq 4$ $\; \; x \geq 0 \;  \; y\geq 0$

we have $dS= \sqrt{z_x^2 + z_y ^2 +1  } = \sqrt{1 +x^2 +y^2}$

$\int_{s}^{} \int_{}^{} \; (x^2+y^2) \; dS = \int_{s}^{} \int_{}^{} \; (x^2+y^2) \sqrt{1 +x^2 +y^2} \; dA $

where $A: x^2 +y^2 \leq 4, \; \; x\geq 0, \; \; y \geq 0$

Using polar coordinates

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2} \; (r^3) \sqrt{1 + r^2} \; \; dr  \; d \theta$

Which I am unable to integrate. How can I continue ?

Comment: Substitute $u=1+r^2$ for the integral in polar coordinates, and note $r^3 = 2r\frac{1}{2}r^2 = 2r\frac{1}{2}(u-1) = \frac{du}{dr} \frac{1}{2} (u-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

With $u=1+r^2$ then $du=2rdr$ and
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2} \; (r^3) \sqrt{1 + r^2} \; \; dr  \; d \theta=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \; d \theta\int_{1}^{5} \; \dfrac{u-1}{2} \sqrt{u} \; \; du  $$